# Azure Runbook - Job could not be stopped

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I have a PowerShell Azure Runbook in a Running state.

Pressing Stop via the Azure Portal results in an error message:

> "Job could not be stopped".

Using the PowerShell cmdlet Stop-AzureRMAutomationJob results in the error message:

> "InternalServerError: {"Message":"An error has occurred."}

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-runbook-execution) it looks like the job will be stopped after 3hrs, but is there any other way to stop a Runbook job or deal with a situation like this?

Answer (score 1):

This issue went to the Microsoft product group to fix and should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

first u should find the job ID with failed status...

Get-AzureRmAutomationJob -ResourceGroupName $RG -AutomationAccountName $AA | where {$*.RunbookName -eq "runbook name" -and $*.status -eq "Failed"}

then after stop the runbook

Stop-AzureRmAutomationJob -ResourceGroupName $RG -AutomationAccountName $AA -id JOBID